# Certificate Revocation List

Tags: certificate

There are many fields on a certificate revocation list (CRL) like Algorithm, Parameters, Issuer Name, This update date, Next update date, user certificate serial #, etc. While I understand the purpose of most of the fields, of what purpose is the field "next update date" on a certificate revocation List?

Answer (score 0):

See RFC 5280: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt

Something similar to the latest date when the next CRL / version of the CRL will be published.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expiry date. Beyond this date this CRL is no longer valid.
It is called "next update" because in normal operations the CRL is supposed to be updated regularly.